# Plotting a pairplot results in a StopIteration Error

Tags: python, seaborn, stopiteration, pairplot

This is my code

```
# create data set
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_dict = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
'B': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
'C': [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
'D': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

# Create a pair plot using seaborn
sns.pairplot(data_frame)
plt.show()
```

and this my pandas and seaborn version

```
1.5.0
0.12.0
```

The Problem

```
------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [67], line 13
     10 data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
     12 # Create a pair plot using seaborn
---> 13 sns.pairplot(data_frame)
     14 plt.show()
```

i try upgrading my seaborn version but and try another ways but the error still the same

Comment: Can you update to the latest pandas? Your example works without issues.

Comment: i did, my latest pandas is 1.5.0

Comment: The latest pandas is 2.1.3, try to update with pip

Comment: @mozway If you tell an inexperienced user to update pandas with pip, and they're using a conda environment, that will likely fubar their environment.

Comment: If you are using the Anaconda distribution, at the Anaconda prompt (base), or your specific environment, use `conda update --all`. If you are not using a distribution, update with `pip` as suggested by @mozway.